# data.timezone in fpm/php.ini has no effect

Tags: php, datetime, yii, webserver

sorry for the mistakes I've made, I'm not Englishman.

Now I'm trying to set my timezone in `php.ini` correctly (/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini). Whatever I typed opposite `date.timezone` (UTC, GMT, Europe/Moscow etc) no one is worked. However, when I set timezone by `date_default_timezone_set()` in my base file everything becomes ok. What do I wrong?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your php.ini is using by web-server? Which timezone phpinfo() show?

Comment: What is the full path to the php.ini file you are editing? It may be the wrong one.

Comment: I don't know why it wasn't work correctly, but after system reboot, everything fall into place! For example, after changing php.ini and applying `service php5-fpm restart` nothing was happened, but now it is working like a charm! Thank guys..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are facing problems in changing it via the php.ini file, you would be better off setting it via **protected/config/main.php** using `'timeZone' => 'UTC',`in the returned array.

Should look something like this -

```
return array(
    'timeZone' => 'UTC',
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
```

To do the same for the session cookie lifetime, add the following in the components array-

```
 'components' => array(

   ...

   'session' => array(
      'cookieParams' => array(
         'lifetime' => 300,
      ),
   ),

),
```

Comment: What is the `main.php` and where exactly I have to set these values? Could you give more concrete answer (with code)?

Comment: Thank you! Good suggestion! Does Yii set these settings automatically at `protected/config/main.php`?

Comment: For example, how can set `session.cookie_lifetime` in main.php?

Comment: hm...Is it anywhere documented? Where can I read about this more detailed?